# Minimum value of $\sum_{k=1}^n|1+z^{(2^k)}|, z\in\mathbb{C}$ in terms of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, maxima-minima

What is the minimum value of $S=\sum_{k=1}^n|1+z^{(2^k)}|, z\in\mathbb{C}$ in terms of $n$ ?

Experimenting on desmos and wolfram suggests the following claims:

> $S$ is minimized when $|z|=1$ and $\arg{z}=\dfrac{\lfloor{\frac{2^n}{3}}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor}{2^n}\pi$  (The numerator is the [Jacobsthal sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C%205%2C%2011%2C%2021%2C%2043&language=english&go=Search).)

> $S_\text{min}=n-f(n)$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\approx0.747771497$

I do not know how to prove any of these claims.

It is easy to show that if $|z|=1$ then $S=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {|\cos{(2^kx)}|}$ where $x=\arg{z}$.

This is related, but I'm not sure if it helps: [$|\cos x|+|\cos 2x|+\cdots+|\cos 2^nx|\geq \dfrac{n}{2\sqrt{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308122/398708).

That's all I've been able to do.

(This question was inspired by similar questions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497017/398708), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497063/398708), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497100/398708) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4093474/398708).)